# Parse query where key contains any object in array

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

My parse class has a property called "postcodes", which is an array of numbers.

In my app, I have an array of "relevantPostcodes". I want to create a query where the postcodes key contains any object from the "relevantPostcodes" array.

Something like  [query whereKey:@"postcodes" containsAnyObjectInArray:relevantPostcodes"]. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, it still seems as though this doesn't work all too reliably. Would love if you could help mate.

Comment: EDIT - I stand corrected, the 'containedIn' method works perfectly. My dataset was incorrect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `[query whereKey:@"postcodes" containedIn:relevantPostcodes]`.  See the [description in the doc](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:notContainedIn:).  Just like the equal to methods, I think it will operate on array type attributes and do what you need.

Comment: I thought this was the case, but it wasn't working for me. I just did some further testing and it appears to work in a normal query, but not when [query fromLocalDatastore]. Same code with same constraints returns results from the cloud, but none from the local datastore, even after confirming the data is the same. Curious. Either a bug or I'm missing something.

Comment: I can't think of a reason other than bug why the same query on the same data would generate different results locally vs remotely.

Comment: Yes, I flagged it and they just confirmed it's a bug.

Comment: Can we have two containedIn, for two separate keys, in one query? query.containedIn("Key1", [2,3,4]); query.containedIn("Key2", [7,8,9]);

Comment: @AceGreen - I don't see why not.  Should be easy to test out.